# Using a mask with an adaptive threshold?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am writing a small program in C++ using OpenCV-2.3 API. 
I have an issue processing an adaptive threshold using a non rectangular mask.

So far, I was performing the adaptive threshold on the whole image and masking afterwards. I realise that,in my case , this was a mistake since the masked pixels would be used to calculate the threshold of my pixels of interest (while I simply want to exclude the former from the analysis)...
However, unlike functions such as cv:: norm, cv::adaptiveThreshold does not seem to support explicitly a mask.

Do you know any obvious solution or workaround? 
Thank you very muck for your suggestions,
Quentin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've written some Python (sorry not c++) code that will allow for masked adaptive thresholding. Its not very fast, but it does what you want, and you may be able to use it as a basis for C++ code. It works as follows:

1. Sets masked pixels in the image to zero.
2. Determines the number of unmasked neighbours within the convolution block for each pixel.
3. Performs a convolution, and averages it by the number of unmasked neighbours within the block. This yields the average value within a pixels neighbourhood block.
4. Thresholds, by comparing the image to the mean neighbourhood values, `mean_conv`
5. Adds the masked off (non-thresholded) part of the image back on.

[image]

The images show, the initial image, the mask, the final processed image.

Here's the code:

```
import cv
import numpy
from scipy import signal

def thresh(a, b, max_value, C):
    return max_value if a > b - C else 0

def mask(a,b):
    return a if b > 100 else 0

def unmask(a,b,c):
    return b if c > 100 else a

v_unmask = numpy.vectorize(unmask)
v_mask = numpy.vectorize(mask)
v_thresh = numpy.vectorize(thresh)

def block_size(size):
    block = numpy.ones((size, size), dtype='d')
    block[(size - 1 ) / 2, (size - 1 ) / 2] = 0
    return block

def get_number_neighbours(mask,block):
    '''returns number of unmasked neighbours of every element within block'''
    mask = mask / 255.0
    return signal.convolve2d(mask, block, mode='same', boundary='symm')

def masked_adaptive_threshold(image,mask,max_value,size,C):
    '''thresholds only using the unmasked elements'''
    block = block_size(size)
    conv = signal.convolve2d(image, block, mode='same', boundary='symm')
    mean_conv = conv / get_number_neighbours(mask,block)
    return v_thresh(image, mean_conv, max_value,C)

image = cv.LoadImageM("image.png", cv.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
mask = cv.LoadImageM("mask.png", cv.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)

#change the images to numpy arrays
original_image = numpy.asarray(image)
mask = numpy.asarray(mask)
# Masks the image, by removing all masked pixels.
# Elements for mask > 100, will be processed
image = v_mask(original_image, mask)
# convolution parameters, size and C are crucial. See discussion in link below.
image = masked_adaptive_threshold(image,mask,max_value=255,size=7,C=5)
# puts the original masked off region of the image back
image = v_unmask(original_image, image, mask)
#change to suitable type for opencv
image = image.astype(numpy.uint8)
#convert back to cvmat
image = cv.fromarray(image)

cv.ShowImage('image', image)
#cv.SaveImage('final.png',image)
cv.WaitKey(0)
```

After writing this I found [this great link](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/adpthrsh.htm) that has a good explanation with plenty of image examples, I used their text image for the above example.

Note. Numpy masks do not seem to be respected by scipy `signal.convolve2d()`, so the above workarounds were necessary.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
I am investigating your suggestion.
Quentin

Comment: @Quentin Geissmann - Did you get it working in your c++ code?

Comment: I think I understood how to implement without making it very slow...
But not yet implemented. :) 
thank you

Comment: You can speed this up by using signal.fftconvolve. Or, even faster, by convolving with a 1-only kernel (which is separable and thus scipy.ndimage.filters.correlate1d can be used) and then subtracting image from conv and mask from number neighbors to get back to the original kernel. Compared to fftconvolve I got a 3x speedup (15s vs 45s). Your original version with convolve2d didn't finish in reasonable time.

Comment: See here for some Python code using correlate1d: https://gist.github.com/neothemachine/9880622 It also includes the method of Quentin's answer using blurring.

Answer (score 4):

According your advices, and after reading your link I wrote this little C++ function:
This is only 1.5 slower than adaptive threshold, but I can probably improve it.

```
void adaptiveThresholdMask(const cv::Mat src,cv::Mat &dst, double maxValue,      cv::Mat mask, int thresholdType, int blockSize, double C){
cv::Mat img, invertMask, noN, conv,kernel(cv::Size(blockSize,blockSize),CV_32F);

/* Makes a image copy of the source image*/
src.copyTo(img);

/* Negates the mask*/
cv::bitwise_not(mask,invertMask);

/* Sets to 0 all pixels out of the mask*/
img = img-invertMask;
/* The two following tasks are both intensive and
 * can be done in parallel (here with OpenMP)*/
#pragma omp parallel sections
{
    {
        /* Convolves "img" each pixels takes the average value of all the pixels in blocksize*/
        cv::blur(img,conv,cv::Size(blockSize,blockSize));
    }
    #pragma omp section
    {
        /* The result of bluring "mask" is proportional to the number of neighbours */
        cv::blur(mask,noN,cv::Size(blockSize,blockSize));
    }
}

 /* Makes a ratio between the convolved image and the number of 
 * neighbours and subtracts from the original image*/
 if(thresholdType==cv::THRESH_BINARY_INV){
    img=255*(conv/noN)-img;
    }
else{
    img=img-255*(conv/noN);
    }

/* Thresholds by the user defined C*/
cv::threshold(img,dst,C,maxValue,cv::THRESH_BINARY);

/* We do not want to keep pixels outside of the mask*/
cv::bitwise_and(mask,dst,dst);

}
```

Thank you again

Comment: nice one :) I think I could greatly speed up my python code, I'll try and get around to it at some point..

Comment: I don't understand this solution. Can you elaborate how this speedup version works? I tried to port it to opencv-python but without success

Comment: It's a very nice solution and super fast (tested in Python), although it becomes a bit inaccurate when your image is very dark, because then you scratch on the integer resolution due to the blur operations.