# Implementing a Simple Adaptive Threshold in GPUImage

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, opencv

I'm developing an iPhone app to recognize some well known symbols from pictures.
I'm basically following these tutorials http://aishack.in/tutorials/sudoku-grabber-with-opencv-detection/ and http://sudokugrab.blogspot.it/2009/07/how-does-it-all-work.html, using OpenCv for template matching and GPUImage for image processing.

When all images are with the same luminance level, I can adjust the threshold of *GPUImageLuminanceThresholdFilter* and all works smooth, but, of course, I can't be sure of the luminance.

So, I need a simple adaptive threshold filter, like the one in those tutorials, which calculate the luminance into the area surrounding each pixel.

The *GPUImageAdaptiveThresholdFilter* doesn't fit my needs, because it detects and sharps the edges, while I need to enhance the symbols.

How can I implement that kind of filter?

Comment: What have you tried? Would scanning a 3x3 or 5x5 area around each pixel, calculating the average luminance, and basing your threshold on that work? Like if the average luminance is 0.1 instead of 0.5, you could lower the threshold by some amount. (I think using the average could be problematic because it would almost guarantee that half the pixels are white and half are black in the resulting image, and you don't want that.) Another option might be to use auto-levels first, or even adaptively around some area of the image, then threshold it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a mask with an adaptive threshold?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9842127/using-a-mask-with-an-adaptive-threshold)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asked to, the awesome Brad Larson added a blur size property to the box blur, and modified the adaptive threshold filter, so it works as expected!
Thanx @BradLarson!